# Spark streaming RDD partitions

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In Spark streaming, is it possible to assign specific RDD partitions to specific nodes in the cluster (for data locality?)

For example, I get a stream of events [a,a,a,b,b,b] and have a 2 node Spark cluster.

I want all a's to always go to Node 1 and all b's to always go to Node 2.

Thanks!

Comment: which stream type are you consuming?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by specifying a custom partitioner for your RDD. The RangeBasedPartitioner will partition your RDD based on range, but you can implement any partitioning logic you with a custom partitioner. Its generally useful/important for partitions to be relatively balanced, and depending on your input data doing something like this could cause problems (e.g. stragglers etc.) so be careful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get that a custom partitioner (in particular the RangePartitioner) will allow me to partition such that a's go here and b's go there but I also want to control the assignment of a partition to a Spark node.

I'm thinking that although the a's go to partition 1, Spark might still choose to have node 2 process partition 1, if node 1 is busy processing something else.

Comment: If this is solely about data locality, Spark already has tuning based on data locality, you can control this by changing `spark.locality.wait`.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into that. Thanks!